# xpath : Get data attribute / value

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract  from a  website  some  product data with Xpath.
Unfortunatly , I don't get it. I am really blocked.

The URL  is the following :
https://www.fertighaus.de/haeuser/suche/

my xpath in Chrome is at the moment  : $x('//*[@id="SearchResultsPage"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jwgc.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jwgc.png)/text()')

this  xpath give an array with an element, I need  a proper xpath  giving me the value of data of this element( price  of the house)  I circled it in yellow in the picture.  I guess it is a small change in this xpath....
If someone  could help me, it would be great. I am new with scraping and scrapy and it it  bite difficult

Thank you very much in advance

[image]

Comment: there is no data available in the page source, which means the page is dynamically loading. You should use selenium or splash for fetching dynamic data along with scrapy here.

Comment: thank you  very much now I understand better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution  was to inspect the all the networking  from  the JS (request mad by the js ). I discovered an API that I could use very easily  :). 
In my  case Splash or  Selenium did not help .